# Correlation between two random variables

Tags: correlation

Show that if $\rho_{XY} = +1$ then $X=a+bY$ for some constants $a,b$ and $b>0$.

How would I go about showing this?

Note: 
$$
\rho_{XY} = \frac{\mbox{Cov}(X,Y)}{\sqrt{\mbox{Var}(X)\mbox{Var}(Y)}}
$$

Comment: Hint: Look up the condition for equality in the Cauchy-Schwarz Inequality used in the proof that $|\rho|\le 1$.

Comment: what does that inequality have to do with this? Is there any way to do this while staying within a probability course. Since the question is on an exam paper, ie. assumes no further knowledge higher than the course.

Comment: I cannot see what then is intended. The result is even technically untrue, the relationship between $X$ and $Y$ only holds with probability $1$.

Comment: @wolfies I'd suggest looking at the date, university term has finished so I have no idea how this could be an assignment. I'd suggest if you can't be bothered to help then leave this website.

Comment: @wolfies: My intention is to not answer the question, but to give a pointer to how one might seek out an answer.

Comment: I have read through every lecture in the course and there is nothing even remotely equivalent to the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality explained so I doubt that is the method to use.

Comment: @user2850514:   It is conceivable that you were asked to prove something else, namely that **if** $X=a+bY$ with $b\gt $0$, **then** $\rho=1$. That is a calculation, using formulas that would be in your notes.

Comment: The question is: Show that the following implication holds: $\rho_{XY} = +1 \implies X = a + bY$ where $b>0$.

Comment: I am not sure the proposition is appropriately worded here. As a counterexample to the wording, as given here, let random variable $X$ have a Bernoulli distribution. Then consider, 

$$\rho_{XY} =  Corr(X, \frac{X+1}{X+2})  = 1$$ 

but where $\frac{X+1}{X+2}$ is not of the linear form $a+bX$. Plainly, one can convert the discrete domain of support {0,1) to {1/2, 2/3} using a linear transformation, but that appears somewhat outside the way the proposition is presented here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $\hat{X}= X-E(X)$ and $\hat{Y}= Y-E(Y)$ denote the de-meaned variables.  Then if $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are any constants

$$\int_{\Omega} (\alpha\hat{X}-\beta\hat{Y})^2dP \geq 0.$$

Let $\alpha = \sqrt{var(Y)}$ and $\beta = \sqrt{var(X)}$. Then

$$\alpha^2\int_{\Omega} \hat{X}^2dP -2\alpha\beta\int_{\Omega} \hat{X}\hat{Y}dP +\beta^2\int_{\Omega}\hat{Y}^2dP \geq 0.$$

Whence, it follows that 
$$2var({X})var({Y})-2\sqrt{var(X)}\sqrt{var(Y)}\int_{\Omega} \hat{X}\hat{Y}dP \geq 0.$$

Dividing both sides by $2$ and the product of non-zero variances we get

$$1-\frac{\int_{\Omega} \hat{X}\hat{Y}dP}{\sqrt{var(X)}\sqrt{var(Y)}} = 1-\rho_{XY} \geq 0.$$
which represents one side of the known correlation constraint $|\rho_{XY}| \leq 1$. In order for equality to hold (i.e., $\rho_{XY}=1$), then the first integral must vanish and the non-negative integrand $(\alpha\hat{X}-\beta\hat{Y})^2$ must almost surely equal $0$:

$$(\alpha\hat{X}-\beta\hat{Y})^2= 0$$

This implies that $X$ and $Y$satisfy the following linear relationship with probability $1$,

$$X-E(X)= \frac{\sqrt{var(X)}}{\sqrt{var(Y)}}[Y-E(Y)]$$

Comment: This is a classical approach to prove (the equality case of) Cauchy-Schwarz inequality.